# Mongodb-mongoose collections undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new and practicing Mongoose and Mongodb connection. I successfully connect my database to my local machine and get log confirmations. I am trying get my collection without passing mongoose Schema but I am getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const app = express();
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected!"))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

var connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.db.collection("bags", function (err, collection) {
  collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, data) {
    console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the DB before the connection is established to MongoDB. ( Connecting to DB is asynchronous code )

Also, Read - https://javascript.info/async-await

---

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB Connected!");
    var connection = mongoose.connection;
    // run logic once db is connected.
    connection.db.collection("bags", function (err, collection) { 
      collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, data) {
        console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
      })
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

---

Or

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', err => { // will trigger connected event when connected to MongoDB
  var connection = mongoose.connection;

  connection.db.collection("bags", function (err, collection) {
    collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, data) {
      console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: I am still getting undefined

Comment: @Krisna Can you print to console `connection.db` ?

Comment: I did. i get this  namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'myFirstDatabase', collection: undefined }

Comment: @Krisna Can you print to console `connection.db.collection("bags")` ?

Comment: Now I can see    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'myFirstDatabase', collection: 'bags' },

Comment: Do you want me to share the screenshot

Comment: @Krisna You're getting the collection now what's is `undefined` now ?

Comment: console data is undefined

Comment: @Krisna can you print `err`,? do you get any errors on console?

Comment: which one connection or collections?

Comment: with data can you print

Comment: @Krisna you don't have access to the database. Read - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/

Comment: Oh ok :D. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Krisna Glad i could help :)

Comment: How do i access it :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231157/discussion-between-krisna-and-tushar-gupta-curioustushar).